# Dell Feature Enhancement Pack & Dell SmartSetting at Startup?

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron

I have these two Dell Feature Enhancement Pack & Dell SmartSetting enabled at Windows Startup, and they consume a lot of RAM, is it necessary to have them running all the time?

The problem, when I check the Task Manager and see what consumers RAM and write a lot to Disk D is those Dell Apps, but I don't know how much performance will be impacted if I disable them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just did, thanks